# CSS + Align Text of a li

Tags: css, flexbox, css-selectors

I have created a dropdown with input using li. I want to align the text of my li 'GGG Filter' to right by a few pixels so that there is some space between '|' and text. How can I achieve that?

[image]

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  height: 85px;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
}

li div {
  width: 15px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border-right: 1px solid #878383;
}
```

```html
<div class="filterdropdown">
  <input placeholder="Enter a filter name"/>
  <div><img src="../Images/ICE.FilterChevron.png"  @click="filters.isShow = !filters.isShow" /></div>
</div>
<div v-if="filters.isShow">
  <ul>
      <li v-on:click="createNew">Create new Filter</li>
      <li v-for="item in filters" v-on:click="filter.changeFilter(item.id,item.name)"><div title="Delete filter" v-on:click.stop="filter.delete(item.id)">x</div>{{ item.name }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to add an extra padding to your li > div except the first li, like this

```
li:not(:first-child) div {
    padding-left:5px;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn’t this be li:first-child, since the question is how to get space in only the first entry?

Comment: It seems to me that the author will want to apply this rule to other lis, as they are similar.

But if you only need the first occurrence, then you are right, you need to change the code a little

li:nth-child(2) div:nth-child(1) {
    padding-left:5px;
}

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add right margin to your X div rule like so:

```css
li div {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```